# Coding a little convenience script, need guidance

Tags: python

So I'm writing a little script to process the output of an analyser we use in the lab joining dozens of CSV files together into a single one which can be easily put into our calculation software (e.g files 1-48). I got as far being able to enter the filename manually in the code which worked great but now I'd like it to be a bit more accessible to everyone else by asking for inputs then performing it using those inputs.

The code as it stands looks like this (I apologise for how awful it is

```
    import sys
    print sys.argv

    (nos)=raw_input ( "Enter Name of Files to Process without numbers: ").strip()
    print "You entered ", (nos)
    (end)= input ("Enter Number of Last File: ")
    (output)= raw_input ("Enter name of output file: ").strip()


    fout = open('%s.csv' % output, 'a')
    for line in open("%s_1.data" % nos):
        fout.write(line)
    # now the rest:    
    for num in range(2,end):
        f = open('%s'+str(num)+'.data' % nos, )
        f.next() # skip the header
        for line in f:
        fout.write(line)
        f.close() # not really needed
    fout.close()
```

So everything seems to be dandy until I reach the bit where I want it to increase the variable and it gives the error 
    TypeError Not all arguments converted during string formatting

So I've made an error somewhere with it understanding the string where the file name changes from USERINPUT_1 to USERINPUT_2. If anyone could help me out or point me to where I could learn to do this right, I would really appreciate it!

Comment: Please provide full error traceback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `str.format` and `with` as I think that is the preferred method.

```
import sys
print sys.argv

nos  = raw_input ( "Enter Name of Files to Process without numbers: ").strip() 
print "You entered ", nos
end= raw_input ("Enter Number of Last File: ") 
output = raw_input ("Enter name of output file: ").strip()

with open ('{}.csv'.format(output), 'a') as fout: #using  "with" means  files will be automatically closed
    with open("{}_1.data".format(nos), 'r') as data:
        for line in data:
                fout.write(line)
#now the rest:
with open('{}.csv'.format(output) , 'a') as fout:
   for num in range(2,int(end)): 
        with open('{}{}.data'.format(nos, num),'r') as f:
            f.next() # skip the header
            for line in f:
                fout.write(line)
```

Comment: This looks good but I'm having a real moron moment here, getting an invalid syntax error on line 11 that I can't figure out in line 11. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, meant line 9. Had extra comments that weren't in your code.

Comment: @user3628194,I edited my code I missed the  "_1" and switched to "nos, num"

Comment: Ok, so I removed the extra _ and removed the f.next() line which gave me trouble in early versions and behold, it seems to work. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the expression `'%s'+str(num)+'.data' % nos`. Since `%` has higher priority than `+`, the expression is parsed as:

```
'%s' + str(num) + ('.data' % nos`)
```

The error now makes sense: since `.data` contains 0 format characters, and you provided one argument to `%`, Python complains. This can be fixed with a pair of parentheses:

```
('%s' + str(num) + '.data') % nos`
```

But it would be much more readable to use the format operator idiomatically, which is to format both variables and combine them:

```
filename = '%s%d.data' % (nos, num)
f = open(filename)
...
```

Unrelated style notes: you don't need parentheses around variables on the left-hand side of assignments. Functions like `input()` and `raw_input()` are best avoided, and such data provided at command-line. This allows users of the script (at least those on decent operating systems) to make use of their shell's editing facilities to edit arguments and of its history to remember arguments from last time.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Equivalent, not necessarily better. Many people actually prefer printf-style formatting, and [it's not going anywhere.](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2014-January/131799.html)

Comment: The [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) say it *"should be preferred to the `%` formatting"* and it avoids these common operator precedence errors, but I accept that there is an element of personal taste.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Agreed. In my experience, the `format` method seems to appeal more to people from Java/C# background, whereas the mod-formatting appeals to people from C/Unix background. It was also my understanding that the mod-formatting was slightly faster, but that may have changed in the meantime.